# Passing class as argument in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I have a Ruby class with all static methods. I want to use these methods in another class. Passing just the class name works but wondering if its the right way to go or is there another way.

```
class Foo
    IDENTIFIER = 'UYT78'
    def self.some_data
      DB.fetch_records
    end

    # and so forth
end

class Bar
    IDENTIFIER = 'XXXXX'
    def self.some_data
      DB.fetch_records
    end

    # and so forth
end

class Reporter

  def report
    Foo.some_data.select {|x| x.id == Foo::identifier}
  end

  def other_report
    Bar.some_data.select {|x| x.id == Foo::identifier}
  end
end
```

Can Reporter be changed to accept Foo as argument to the methods so these methods can be re-used based on the argument being passed?

```
Reporter.report(Foo)
Reporter.report(Bar)
```

and report method looks like

```
def report(klass)
  klass.some_data.select {|x| x.id == Foo::identifier}
end
```

This approach works but passing a class name like this as argument doesn't feel right? Or may be it is?

Comment: You’re probably going to come up against split opinions, here. Passing a class as an argument is definitely a valid approach, but that can be over used or get confusing sometimes. Passing a class as a string adds more complexity, tho, for no real gain, so I don’t suggest that. Personally I’d define the report and some_data methods in a module, and include it in both classes, since the only difference appears to be a constant defined against the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine... generally it's referred to as `duck-typing`... as long as the class passed supports `#some_data` method, it doesn't really matter what specific class it is.  If it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck...

It's possible you may want to store the target class at initialization.

```
class Reporter
  attr_accessor :klass
  def initialize(klass)
    self.klass = klass
  end

  def report
    klass.some_data.select
  end
end

my_foo_reporter = Reporter.new(Foo)

my_foo_reporter.report # calls some_date on Foo class
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is nice but rather than passing the class like that I would use ruby's `require`.

**foo.rb**

```
class Foo
  IDENTIFIER = 'UYT78'.freeze

  def self.some_data
    'Foo'
  end
end
```

**bar.rb**

```
class Bar
  IDENTIFIER = 'XXXXX'.freeze

  def self.some_data
    'Bar'
  end
end
```

**reporter.rb**

```
require './foo'
require './bar'

class Reporter

  def report
    p Foo.some_data
    p Foo::IDENTIFIER
  end

  def other_report
    p Bar.some_data
    p Bar::IDENTIFIER
  end
end

Reporter.new.report
puts '----------------'
Reporter.new.other_report
```

Which would return like below (Just and example)-

```
"Foo"
"UYT78"
----------------
"Bar"
"XXXXX"
```

In my opinion it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
class Foo
  IDENTIFIER = 'UYT78'
  def self.some_data
    ['ABC21', 'UYT78']
  end
end
```

```
class Bar
  IDENTIFIER = 'XXXXX'
  def self.some_data
    ['XXXXX', 'DEF38']
  end
end
```

```
class Reporter
  def report(klass)
    k = Module.const_get(klass)
    k.public_send(:some_data).select {|x| x == k::IDENTIFIER}
  end
end
```

```
reporter = Reporter.new
```

```
reporter.report("Foo") #=> ["UYT78"] 
reporter.report("Bar") #=> ["XXXXX"] 
reporter.report(:Bar)  #=> ["XXXXX"]
```